# Python WebScraping - Trying to find rows in a Table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to webscrape a table where I want to extract most of the td data from the table. I can get some from the rows but I cannot get the individual tds properly. What do I need to do to extract the td data? I need to get the data in tds where the name is anything like, standing-table__cell, or I could just get the data in all tds and sort through it

Sample of the output -

```
[<tr class="standing-table__row">
<th class="standing-table__cell standing-table__header-cell" data-index="0" data-label="pos" title="Position">#</th>
<th class="standing-table__cell standing-table__header-cell standing-table__cell--name" data-index="1" title="Team">Team</th>
<th class="standing-table__cell standing-table__header-cell" data-index="2" data-label="pld" title="Played">Pl</th>
<th class="standing-table__cell standing-table__header-cell" data-index="9" data-label="pts" data-sort-value="use-attribute">Pts</th>
<th class="standing-table__cell standing-table__header-cell is-hidden--bp15 is-hidden--bp35 " data-index="10" data-sort-value="use-attribute">Last 6</th>
</tr>, <tr class="standing-table__row" data-item-id="345">
<td class="standing-table__cell">1</td>
<td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name" data-long-name="Manchester City" data-short-name="Manchester City">
<a class="standing-table__cell--name-link" href="/manchester-city">Manchester City</a>
</td>
<td class="standing-table__cell">9</td>
<td class="standing-table__cell is-hidden--bp15 is-hidden--bp35 " data-sort-value="16313333">
<div class="standing-table__form">
<span class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win" title="Manchester City 2-1 Newcastle United"> </span><span class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win" title="Manchester City 3-0 Fulham"> </span><span class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win" title="Cardiff City 0-5 Manchester City"> </span><span class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win" title="Manchester City 2-0 Brighton and Hove Albion"> </span><span class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--draw" title="Liverpool 0-0 Manchester City"> </span><span class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win" title="Manchester City 5-0 Burnley"> </span> </div>
</td>
</tr>, <tr class="standing-table__row" data-item-id="155">
<td class="standing-table__cell">2</td>
<td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name" data-long-name="Liverpool" data-short-name="Liverpool">
  File "C:\Users\scrape.py", line 18, in <module>
    for td in premier_soup_tr.find_all('td', {'class': 'standing-table__cell'}):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1884, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
>>>
```

My code -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table'
premier_r = requests.get(url)
print(premier_r.status_code)
premier_soup = BeautifulSoup(premier_r.text, 'html.parser')
premier_soup_tr = premier_soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'standing-table__row'})
print(premier_soup_tr)
for td in premier_soup_tr.find_all('td', {'class': 'standing-table__cell'}):
    print(td)
```

The html source looks like -

```
    <tr class="standing-table__row" data-item-id="345">
  <td class="standing-table__cell">1</td>
  <td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name" data-short-name="Manchester City" data-long-name="Manchester City">

            <a href="/manchester-city" class="standing-table__cell--name-link">Manchester City</a>

  </td>
  <td class="standing-table__cell">9</td>
  <td class="standing-table__cell">23</td>
  <td class="standing-table__cell is-hidden--bp15 is-hidden--bp35 " data-sort-value="16313333">
          <div class="standing-table__form">
      <span title="Manchester City 2-1 Newcastle United" class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win"> </span><span title="Manchester City 3-0 Fulham" class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win"> </span><span title="Cardiff City 0-5 Manchester City" class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win"> </span><span title="Manchester City 2-0 Brighton and Hove Albion" class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win"> </span><span title="Liverpool 0-0 Manchester City" class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--draw"> </span><span title="Manchester City 5-0 Burnley" class="standing-table__form-cell standing-table__form-cell--win"> </span>        </div>
        </td>

</tr>
    <tr class="standing-table__row" data-item-id="155">
  <td class="standing-table__cell">2</td>
  <td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name" data-short-name="Liverpool" data-long-name="Liverpool">

            <a href="/liverpool" class="standing-table__cell--name-link">Liverpool</a>

  </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You done right in idea , but you have to do something on what you got , and `find_all` will return a set of result , you can not do like `premier_soup_tr.find_all` , the right way is `premier_soup_tr[position].find_all`

This is what i did.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table'
premier_r = requests.get(url)
print(premier_r.status_code)
premier_soup = BeautifulSoup(premier_r.text, 'html.parser')
premier_soup_tr = premier_soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'standing-table__row'})
result = [[r.text.strip() for r in td.find_all('td', {'class': 'standing-table__cell'})][:-1] for td in premier_soup_tr[1:]]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'Manchester City', '9', '7', '2', '0', '26', '3', '23', '23'], ['2', 'Liverpool', '9', '7', '2', '0', '16', '3', '13', '23'], ['3', 'Chelsea', '9', '6', '3', '0', '20', '7', '13', '21'], ['4', 'Arsenal', '9', '7', '0', '2', '22', '11', '11', '21'], ['5', 'Tottenham Hotspur', '9', '7', '0', '2', '16', '7', '9', '21'], ['6', 'Bournemouth', '9', '5', '2', '2', '16', '12', '4', '17'],
```

Comment: Thanks. The line that starts with result looks pretty complicated though!

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the result line does..? Is it stripping whitespace from the 2nd item to the 2nd to last?

Comment: iter each element in `premier_soup_tr` , which contain several `<td></td>`. `[r.text.strip() for r in td.find_all...` will extract each text and remove `\n` .
`[:-1]` and `[1:]` are determining to pass the empty result @anfield

Comment: Thanks. But I am a bit confused as to why this wouldnt work for example (once you have the rows)
Why wouldnt the second line work, the td in premer_soup.find_all part..? In the first line we have the rows. In the second we try and get the tds in each row..
  
premier_soup_tr = premier_soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'standing-table__row'})
  
for td in premier_soup_tr.find_all('td', {'class': 'standing-table__cell'}):
    print(td)

Comment: As my answer, `find_all` will return a list , you can not do `find_all` to a list. But you can do for each elements in it @anfield

Comment: Thanks. Another question - How would I also extract the href link from the td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name. This is the 2nd cell after position, then comes the cell with team name and the href i want inside that

Comment: `print([a.find("a",href=True)["href"] for a in premier_soup_tr[1:]])` @anfield